# how to save a file in file storage (local driver) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file

i have this ajax to insert in db with Laravel.

```
$(document).one('click','.insertar', function () {
           //var seleccion_etiquetas = $('#seleccion_editar_etiquetas').select2("val");+'&id_etiquetas='+seleccion_etiquetas

            var id ="";
            var data = $('#datos').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/inserta/"+id,
                data: data+'&fotos='+$("#formulario input[name='fotos']").val(),
                success: function () {
                    $('#formulario input[type="text"]').val("");
                    tablalocales.ajax.reload();

                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#seleccion_editar_etiquetas").val(null).trigger("change");

                }
            });
        });
```

And returns this:

```
_token: XtpzU3lBFvmTPdRisMqkwxs83dTH1xlLx2OZVQNT
nombre: qwe
direccion: asd
seleccion_editar: 1
id_locales: 
id_etiquetas[]: 1
**fotos: C:\fakepath\relaciones.png**
inserta/
```

and i want to insert in the controller with:

```
$local = new Local();
$local->nombre = $pedido->nombre;
$local->direccion = $pedido->direccion;
$local->idfamilias = $pedido->seleccion_editar;
// with this -->  $local = $pedido->file('fotos')->store('storage/app/public');

$local->save();
```

and in the console i make the first step of file storage
**php artisan storage:link**
and i only want to upload file into Storage/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: the question is, how can i do it to insert into database and upload to the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

With this command you store the file on the file system.
And as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads) `The path to the file will be returned by the store method so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your database.`

In your case should be something like this:

```
$path = $pedido->file('fotos')->store('your_dir_name');
$local->file_url = $path;
```

Comment: No. The idea is that you store the file on your file system (with `$path = $pedido->file('fotos')->store('your_dir_name');`) and them in the database you have path to the file (with `$local->file_url = $path;`).